# ML : Warning: match nonexhaustive

Tags: sml, ml

This is the question:

We represent polynomials using the following type:

```
datatype exp = Const of int | x | Add of exp * exp | Mult of exp * exp | Power of exp * int
```

For instance, the expression `Add (Add (Mult (Const 3, Power (x, 2)), Mult (Const 6, x)), Const 1)`
represents the polynomial `3x2 + 6x + 1`.

(a) Write a function "evaluate" to evaluate a given expression `e` for a specific value of `x`.

And this is my answer:

```
datatype exp = Const of int | x | Add of exp * exp | Mult of exp * exp |Power of exp * int
fun pow(a,0) = 1 | pow(a,1) = a | pow(a,b) = mult(a,pow(a,b-1));
fun evaluate(Const(a),t) = a 
| evaluate(x,t) = t 
| evaluate(Add(a,x),t)= (evaluate(a,t)+t) 
| evaluate(Mult(a,x),t) = (evaluate(a,t)*t) 
| evaluate(Power(x,a),t) = pow(t,a);
val y = Add (Add (Mult (Const 3, Power (x, 2)), Mult (Const 6, x)), Const 1);
evaluate(y,1);
```

But the result is :

```
uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]
raised at: stdIn:6.37
```

Also after defining the function `evaluation` I have this warning:

```
stdIn:1.6-6.37 Warning: match nonexhaustive
      (Const a,t) => ...
      (x,t) => ...
      (Add (a,x),t) => ...
      (Mult (a,x),t) => ...
      (Power (x,a),t) => ...
val evaluate = fn : exp * int -> int
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only matching on terms containing `x`; you need to take into account arbitrary `exp`s and evaluate all of them recursively.

For example, replace

```
evaluate(Add(a,x),t)= (evaluate(a,t)+t)
```

with

```
evaluate (Add(e1, e2), t) = evaluate(e1, t) + evaluate(e2, t)
```

Comment: there is another question:
Write a function "derive" to compute the derivative of a polynomial expression according to the
following rules:
c' = 0
x' = 1
(u + v)' = u' + v'
(u.v)' = u'.v + u.v'
(un)' = n.un-1.u'

i write this function:
fun derv(Const(a)) = 0 | derv(x) = 1 | derv(Add(u,v)) = derv(u) + derv(v) | derv(Mult(u, v)) = (derv(u)*v) + (u*derv(v)) | derv(Power(u,n)) = n*pow(u, n-1)*derv(u);

but its not working.
there is datatype exception...

Comment: Translating the rules is very straightforward, but the result will be an `exp` instead of a number - `derive x = Const 1`; `derive (Add(u, v) = Add(derive u, derive v)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the warning because your patterns don't cover all cases. For example -- and `Add` pattern should look like `Add(a,b)` since this covers all possible cases. For example,

In the expression `2x^3 + 3x^2`, `a` would bind to `2x^3` and `b` to `3x^2` (all suitably translated into your datatype of course). But -- in your `evaluate` you use patterns like `Add(a,x)` -- which will only capture polynomials which look something like `2x^3 + x`. I see absolutely no reason to assume that the second term in the sum is `x`. Similar remarks hold for your other patterns (other than the first pattern for `x` itself). In all cases, replace your patterns that look like `Add(a,x)` by patterns that look like `Add(a,b)` and think carefully about what to return in those cases.